# Why is the minimum video memory for a virtualbox machine so large?

Tags: virtualbox, video, ram

I'm creating many virtualbox systems with clean installs and such and noticed that the default video memory size is *quite large*. I could understand at the beginning of the Ubuntu installation a VGA screen is used. I'm not too sure of the dimensions and color depth used, but I would imagine that's quite small. (0.5Mb?)

Then I end up using those systems in plain console mode.

What would be the minimum required to run that? Can't I just put 1Mb and be good with it and save some memory when running those vitualbox systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer: Yes.

If you experience lag just adjust it. Even though I use just the console I adjust it to way more than 1MB just because im always flying all over the place.

The default recommended video memory for SERVERS on VB is ~9MB

Comment: I put 9Mb at this point, because the system asked to do that min. but it seems to be that 6 consoles of 80x25 characters x2 since it uses 16 bits (8 bit for the character and 8 bits for the color), that's a whooping 24,000... so 1Mb is really a killer, right?! Obviously, I'm not trying to make use of a large console or an enhance graphical console.